# How do I link a method instead of string to Path of RadzenLink

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a `RadzenLink` and I want it to run a particular method when clicked. I'm doing it like this:

```
<RadzenLink Path=@OnReset Style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px;" Text="Reset" />
```

The `OnReset` is:

```
    protected void OnReset()
    {
        nameFirst = string.Empty;
        nameLast = string.Empty;
    }
```

I get an error on `@OnReset` at `Path` property that reads:

> Cannot convert method group to string

So how do I provide a method to [RadzenLink](https://blazor.radzen.com/link)?

Comment: What is `RadzenLink`, exactly?

Comment: RazdenLink maps the Parameter directly to the HREF on the NavLink it wraps. Try `@onclick="..."` as it also supports attribute splatting.
https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor/blob/master/Radzen.Blazor/RadzenLink.razor

Comment: Path expects a string, and you've given it a method, hence the error.  See @BrianParker suggestion above.